# Button click adds text to EditText window

Tags: c#, android, button, android-edittext

I'm building a text to speech app for android. I have a functioning EditText window. Whatever is typed into the window is spoken at the click of a button. What I want to do next is to build a sentence for output by adding text to the EditText window through button clicks.

This is my "speak" function. Can I manipulate and append to the editText.Text to accomplish my goal?

```
        speak.Click += delegate
        {
           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(editText.Text))
           textToSpeech.Speak(editText.Text, QueueMode.Flush, null);
        };



    <EditText
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:text="What would you like to say?" />
     <Button
        android:text="Speak"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/speak" />
```

Comment: "What I want to do next is to build a sentence for output by adding text to the EditText window through button clicks."- when want to add a sentence back to the EditText with the same Button after speaking?

Comment: No, I have additional buttons with the text needed to build a sentence.

Comment: btw what language? that doesn't look like Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding the question but this may work for you:

```
String text = "whatever"; 
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
    editText.append(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
String speechText = editText.Text;

buildSentence.Click += delegate{
    String sentenceToBuild = "This is the sentence I want to build";
    sentenceToBuild += speechText;
    editText.Text = sentenceToBuild;
}
```